# vue3 devtools: How to access component methods using Options API?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-devtools, vue-options-api

In devtools with `Vue2` I can access my components methods by selecting a component in `vue devtools` and then type `$vm0.myMethod()` in the console.

```js
export default {
  // ...
  methods: {
    myMethod() {
      console.log('hello');
    },
  }
  // ...
}
```

Now I'm using `Vue3` with options API. How can I still access my component methods?

Comment: Really interested by that one too!

Comment: @kissu It's available on $vm.proxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the methods are specified in `methods` for options API: {

```html
<script>
export default {
  expose: ['publicMethod'],
  methods: {
    privateMethod() {...}
    publicMethod() {...}
  },
}
</script>
```

For composition API, it's presumed that component methods are returned from setup function:

```html
<script>
export default {
  setup(props, ctx) {
    function justLocalFunction() {...}
    function privateMethod() {...}
    function publicMethod() {...}

    ctx.expose({ publicMethod })

    return { privateMethod, publicMethod };
  }
}
</script>
```

This is implicitly done with `script setup` syntax:

```html
<script setup>
export default {
  setup(props, ctx) {
    {
      // Block scope isn't magically transformed
      function justLocalFunction() {...}
    }

    function privateMethod() {...}
    function publicMethod() {...}

    defineExpose({ publicMethod })
  }
}
</script>
```

Here only `publicMethod` is available on component ref. While `privateMethod` and `publicMethod` are exposed on internal component instance, which can be accessed as `getCurrentInstance().proxy.privateMethod`, etc inside setup block, and as devtools `$vm.proxy` via Vue devtools.

If there's a chance that `justLocalFunction` needs to be accessed later, returning it from setup function will make it easier for testing and debugging.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, a regular `script` is not closed by default. Wasn't closed in Vue2 at least, it's only the default API for `script setup` as [told here](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineexpose).

Comment: @kissu That's correct. `expose` is explicitly used make this behaviour consistence consistence between snippets. All properties are still available on internal instance any way.